# IllegalArgumentException thrown from org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.expressiontyper.ExpressionTyper

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I spent a whole bunch of time today working out a problem that occurred on migrating from Optaplanner 7.48 to Optaplanner 8.3.0 The problem seems to me to be actually in the 7.50 version of Drools that Optaplanner 8.3 depends on.

```
rule "applyHomeTeamConstraints"
  enabled true
    when $f1: ProblemFixture(slot != null, $ht: homeTeam)
         $tu: ProblemSoftConstraint(this memberOf $ht.constraints,
                                  matches($f1.slot.dateTime) )
    then
        scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext, -$tu.getWeight());
end
```

The rule worked perfectly happily in Optaplanner 7.48/Drools 7.48.

When I use this rule in my Optaplanner 8.3.0/Drools 7.50 project, I get an exceptionally unhelpful message...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at uk.me.selwyn_family.league.scheduler.solver.SolverTest.testBuildSeasonSolver(SolverTest.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at uk.me.selwyn_family.league.scheduler.solver.SolverTest.testBuildSeasonSolver(SolverTest.java:47)
```

After many hours of tracing I found that the exception was actually thrown at line 243 in org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.expressiontyper.ExpressionTyper

```
Expression parentLeft = findLeftLeafOfNameExpr(halfPointFreeExpr.getParentNode().orElseThrow(UnsupportedOperationException::new));
```

and occurs because the parentNode is null.

I can solve the problem by simply add `this.` in front of the `matches()` as follows...

```
rule "applyHomeTeamConstraints"
  enabled true
    when $f1: ProblemFixture(slot != null, $ht: homeTeam)
         $tu: ProblemSoftConstraint(this memberOf $ht.constraints,
                                  this.matches($f1.slot.dateTime) )
    then
        scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext, -$tu.getWeight());
end
```

I am trying to work out whether it was only working by accident in the 7.48 version and actually should never have worked or whether a bug has crept into the Drools 7.50 that should be reported.

Either way a more helpful error message would be good!

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Update: Now I have told Surefire not to trimStackTrace here is the full trace...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:280)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:103)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:68)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:116)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.getScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:73)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.ScoreManager.create(ScoreManager.java:59)
    at uk.me.selwyn_family.league.scheduler.solver.SeasonSolver.<init>(SeasonSolver.java:31)
    at uk.me.selwyn_family.league.scheduler.solver.SolverTest.testBuildSeasonSolver(SolverTest.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:696)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:882)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1189)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.expressiontyper.ExpressionTyper.toTypedExpressionRec(ExpressionTyper.java:243)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.expressiontyper.ExpressionTyper.toTypedExpression(ExpressionTyper.java:153)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.getDrlxParseResult(ConstraintParser.java:174)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.drlxparse.ConstraintParser.drlxParse(ConstraintParser.java:104)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.pattern.PatternDSL.findAllConstraint(PatternDSL.java:139)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.pattern.PatternDSL.buildPattern(PatternDSL.java:241)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.ModelGeneratorVisitor.visit(ModelGeneratorVisitor.java:145)
    at org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.PatternDescr.accept(PatternDescr.java:303)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.AndVisitor.visit(AndVisitor.java:50)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.visitor.ModelGeneratorVisitor.visit(ModelGeneratorVisitor.java:86)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ModelGenerator.processRule(ModelGenerator.java:187)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.generator.ModelGenerator.generateModel(ModelGenerator.java:160)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl.compileKnowledgePackages(ModelBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl.buildRules(ModelBuilderImpl.java:220)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.builder.ModelBuilderImpl.postBuild(ModelBuilderImpl.java:130)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:115)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:99)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:268)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:216)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:80)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:277)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:245)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:202)
    at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.getKieContainer(KieHelper.java:100)
    at org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper.build(KieHelper.java:82)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:272)
    ... 36 more
```

(No wonder it took me a long time to trace!!!)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a regression in Drools. Yes, that error message isn't helpful - that too is an issue (note that Drools has improved a lot to get better error messages and the new way to write constraints (ConstraintStreams) has far more useful stacktraces).

One thing that doesn't make sense to me is your stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is an error in a scoreDrl or scoreDrlFile.
    at uk.me.selwyn_family.league.scheduler.solver.SolverTest.testBuildSeasonSolver(SolverTest.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at uk.me.selwyn_family.league.scheduler.solver.SolverTest.testBuildSeasonSolver(SolverTest.java:47)
```

This stacktrace doesn't mention lines of `org.optaplanner` or `org.drools`. Can  you please share the code of `SolverTest.java:47` too so we can verify it doesn't covert/eat the exception? The message does seem to come from OptaPlanner, but a true OptaPlanner exception would have a chained (= caused by) exception coming from a line in org.drools with hopefully more information for us to diagnose why it doesn't give a proper error message.

Comment: It is possible that this is a regression. Would you mind filing a JIRA and attaching an executable code that will show the problem?

Comment: This is a very simple TestNG test that I was running using Maven Surefire. I also was confused by the lack of a full stack trace. I have just realised that I could have saved myself several hours of debugging by telling Surefire not to "trimStackTrace"!!! You live and learn :-) I will add the full stack trace to my original post.